# Enforce a minimum balance of 0 in decimal column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `User` model `has_one` `Account` which has a `balance` column.

Observe:

```
> alice = User.first
 => #<User id: 1, charge_fee: nil, created_at: "2016-03-19 20:15:14", updated_at: "2016-03-19 20:15:14"> 
> bob = User.second
 => #<User id: 2, charge_fee: nil, created_at: "2016-03-19 20:15:18", updated_at: "2016-03-19 20:15:18"> 
> alice.account.balance.to_s
 => "50.0" 
> bob.account.balance.to_s
 => "50.0"
```

When one user transfers money to another, the sender's balance decreases, and the receiver's increases:

```
> alice.account.transfer(to: bob.account, amount:25)
 => nil 
> alice.account.balance.to_s
 => "25.0" 
> bob.account.balance.to_s
 => "75.0"
```

The system is perfect, except that users can transfer more money than they have, and their balance goes into negative:

```
> alice.account.transfer(to:bob.account, amount:50)
 => nil 
> alice.account.balance.to_s
 => "-25.0" 
> bob.account.balance.to_s
 => "125.0"
```

How do I enforce it so that the command `Account.decrement!('balance', amount)` fails if `account.balance` falls below `0`?

Full source of this application can be found [here](https://github.com/amingilani/rails-bank-app). The actual `increment!` and `decrement!` happens [here](https://github.com/amingilani/rails-bank-app/blob/master/app/models/account.rb#L55), here's the excerpt:

```
Account.transaction do
  Transaction.create(transaction)
  transaction[:to].increment!('balance', transaction[:amount])
  transaction[:from].decrement!('balance', transaction[:amount])

  Transaction.create(fee_transaction) if transaction[:transfer]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fail 'Balance cannot be negative' if
      transaction[:from].balance < BigDecimal('0') &&
      transaction[:from].meta? == false

Comment: Wow, ummm.. your formatting sucks, but this is exactly the line of code I needed to insert in the transaction! Thank you.

I'll explain for other people:
I'm doing a transaction [here](https://github.com/amingilani/rails-bank-app/blob/master/app/models/account.rb#L55). This code fails the transaction unless it's a meta account (like deposit, whose normal balance is negative). @waleedvic, did you actually read the whole codebase to figure out the meta flag or something?

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that [`decrement!` skips validations](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/decrement). To get the behavior you want, you're going to need to write something like it yourself. One simple way is to validate that the `balance` is at least 0 and use `update_attributes` to set the new amount. You can use [`ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) and `reload` to ensure atomicity.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :balance, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  def withdraw!(amount)
    transaction do
      reload
      update_attributes!(balance: balance - amount)
    end
  end
end
```

You could also do the check directly in the `withdraw!` method, if you have some reason to not use Rails' validations (maybe sometimes people can overdraw their checking account). Then you can still use `decrement!` if you prefer it.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  def withdraw!(amount)
    transaction do
      reload
      raise 'Insufficient funds' unless balance >= amount
      decrement!('balance', amount)
    end
  end
end
```

Depending what else is going on, maybe you can skip the `reload` to avoid the extra database query, as long as you're confident you have an up-to-date record.

Comment: Thank you, however, and I'll update the question with this too, the actual `increment` and `decrement` was done in one fell transaction [here](https://github.com/amingilani/rails-bank-app/blob/master/app/models/account.rb#L55), and while your code works, the marked answer actually provides a way for the transaction to fail if the funds are too low. It's ACID because it still uses the `decrement!` function, and checks if the account is a meta account (e.g. deposits, which will have a normal balance in negative) the other answer addresses both of these with the codebase.